# 438 error with ListObject("Table1").DataBodyRange.PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I get runtime error on:

```
z = lr1 + x - 1
With Worksheets("b")
    .Activate
    .Cells(2 + i, 2).Copy
     '(error in here)---------------v
    .ListObjects("Tabela20").DataBodyRange(z, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 End With
```

i've tried with just ".paste" or changeing Worksheets("b") to ActiveSheet
or

```
z = lr1 + x - 1
With Worksheets("b")
    .Activate
    .Cells(2 + i, 2).Copy Destination:=.ListObjects("Tabela20").DataBodyRange(z, 1)
 End With
```

This macro worked a week ago.

Comment: Can you build a [mcve]? And check the value of `z`, by writing `MsgBox z` on the line before the error. Probably it is more or less than the rows of `Tabela20`.

Comment: z it's ok, even if I put any number instead of it I get an error

Comment: That's good. Now really, try to create a [mcve], and post it. Post a screenshot of how `Tabela20` and your question would be solved pretty quickly.

Comment: it worked when i added 2 more rows to table. Why it didn' work with one row table(+headers)?

Comment: No idea. The best case for you is to build a [mcve].